# Casting and using different overridden method of new class in C++

Tags: c++, class, casting

I have two derived classes off an abstract base class. The derived classes each have their separate implementations that overrides the virtual function func() in the base class. I create an object of derivedClass1 called 'a', and run func() from it.

This creates an object of derivedClass1 called teleporter, the memory address of which is casted to an object of derivedClass2 called teleported. Next I run func() from teleported, which is an object of derivedClass2, but this does not work, and it simply runs func() in derivedClass1 in an endless recursive loop.

This is a simplification, in fact I use this in a code where derivedClass1 teleporter contains certain values (inherited from baseClass and shared with derived 1 and 2), that I wish to pass onto the other derived class. This is because I wish to access the other classes' functions with the same object. I know, I could simply create a new object and copy each value separately, but this is a fairly large program so I'd rather not have to change it all if possible. If it is possible to access the typecasted classes' overridden methods instead of the old methods.

```
using namespace std;

class baseClass {
protected:
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;

};

class derivedClass2 : public baseClass {
public:
    void func() override {
        cout << "Derivation 2 running.\n";
    }
};

class derivedClass1 : public baseClass {
public:
    void func() {
        cout << "Derivation 1 running.\n";
        derivedClass1 teleporter;
        derivedClass2* teleported = (derivedClass2*)(&teleporter);
        teleported->func();
    }
};

int main() {
    derivedClass1 a;
    a.func();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Derivation 1 is running.
Derivation 1 is running.
Derivation 1 is running.
Derivation 1 is running.
....
```

Desired Result:

```
Derivation 1 is running.
Derivation 2 is running.
```

**Update:**
As I was told I was using old C type casting, I tried C++ styles of casting. static_cast and const_cast did not run, dynamic_cast gave nullptr as the conversion was unsuccessful, and reinterpret_cast gave the same result as C type casting.

Comment: Dereferencing of `teleported` causes Undefined Behavior because it still points to the instance of `derivedClass1`.

Comment: `(derivedClass2*)(&teleporter)` -- You are using a C-style cast, and you lose all the automatic error checking you would get if you used C++ style casts.

Comment: Why don't you write it like `derivedClass2 teleporter; teleporter.func();`? No need to involve casting.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm sorry, I'd use C++ style casts but I'm unfamiliar with them, please let me know of a better solution/implementation

Comment: @vahancho Ah, because actually this is a simplification. In truth, it's more like derivedClass1 teleported is involved because only during runtime do I know if it will be casted to derivedClass2 or derivedClass3. Otherwise I would simply create an object off derivedClass2, yes.

Comment: [static_cast<>, const_cast<>, dynamic_cast<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), etc.  Drop the usage of casting the way you're doing them.  If you replaced that cast with `static_cast<derivedClass2*>`, the compiler would have given you the error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried the various C++ types of casting. Stating and const gave an error, dynamic returned nullptr and did not work either, and reinterpret gave same result as C. Is this truly not achievable?

Comment: @Terrornado -- LOL.  That is exactly the purpose of those casts -- to give you an error, and to let you know what you're doing is dangerous.  With a C-style cast, you can cast basically any type to any type -- that is playing with dynamite, and you blew yourself up.

Comment: Casting between objects of `derivedClass1` and `derivedClass2` is simply not allowed. The fact that both share the same base class is not enough for casting. You likely need to make a new object.

Comment: @Terrornado *This is because I wish to access the other classes' functions with the same object* -- You really need to take a step back and look at your design if this is what you've concluded you must do.

Comment: Well thanks everyone. I've let go of the idea of implementing this, and instead made a constructor for the derived classes to pass all the values easily from derivedClass1 object to derivedClass2 object after creating a wholly new derivedClass2 object, avoiding the casting issues altogether. Any answers to close this question?

Comment: @Terrornado: You’d have to edit the question to ask if this is possible (it isn’t) rather than phrasing it as a request to debug your code (which is impossible).